# import error while importing stmp library showing no module

Tags: python

while importing stmplib in python shell 3.4.1 i am getting an error below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
   import stmplib
```

ImportError: No module named 'stmplib'

in anaconda  i am getting an error like

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-0aa4d90aba56> in <module>()
----> 1 import stmplib

ImportError: No module named 'stmplib'
```

I don't know where to check. so need help in below things

-if i need to install any module.how to do that pip install what

-need a link to download that module .so link

-or some path issues are there

but i am able to import

```
import  email.utils
```

so what may be reason please suggest.

Comment: Simple Mail Transfer Protocol -> `smtp` not `stmp`.

Comment: sorry for asking this question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The module is `smtplib`, not `stmplib`.